# Asp.Net MVC Style Bundles don't Render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, styles, rendering, bundle

i'm working on a project which it uses styles and scripts bundles, but when I run it locally, everything works perfectly but when I deploy it, non of style bundles render.

here is my bundle :

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/assets/bootstrap").Include(
            "~/Assets/css/bootstrap.css"
            ));
```

I'm wondering why is this happening after deploy?

before deploy (even in release mode) :

`<link href="/assets/bootstrap?v=hU1wN6BEpBTuIe8JohSVK3KT4N99k1wLPo3p56yO0I81" rel="stylesheet">`

after deploy (even in debug mode) :

`<link href="/assets/bootstrap-rtl?v=" rel="stylesheet">`

**Update:** according to answer I changed the bundle like so :

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/abcdefg").Include(
    "~/Assets/css/bootstrap.css"
    ));
```

which I don't have a real folder named `abcdefg` , but it didn't make any change and still the problem persists :

`<link href="/abcdefg?v=" rel="stylesheet">`

so if anybody knows where's the problem or what I am doing wrong, I'll be grateful to get your helps

Comment: Can you show how you are referencing it in the view/_Layout

Comment: @Izzy `@Styles.Render("~/abcdefg")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find out that the problem was because that I've forgotten to include the style files in the project before I publish it.

so I've included them and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe someone already got a similar problem.

[Style bundling not working after IIS deployment (MVC 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946685/style-bundling-not-working-after-iis-deployment-mvc-4)

Make sure you have no name collision