# JS Script Broke After Minification

Tags: javascript, json, minify

After Minification my Jquery Stops Working and Gives Error

JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

If I Remove Minification My Scrips Works Fine..

Comment: what process have u followed for minification?

Comment: Using MVC  BundleCollection

Comment: This might not be problem with js, but problem with your code!

Comment: What I have understand is that , you are saying that  i have some syntax errors in code which causes minification errors

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379130/asp-net-mvc-4-script-bundling-causes-errors-upon-deployment

Comment: Thanks Varpe .Really its so nice of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Solved: In my case it was the version issue between **Jquery** ,**jQuery.Validation** and **jquery.unobtrusive**.what i did i simply updated the files and now its working .thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 0):

you should put 'debugger;' instruction to the start of js execution and then continue step by step (firefox/chrome). when you find the error, you must be able to tell whether it's a minification error or yours.

Comment: this lin throws Error                                                                            {return JSON.parse(n+"")};

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that this line works without minification? I don't see any syntax error

Comment: you better post your code here, but you must first find the smallest problematic section of your code, don't post it all. and by the way, is that return statement inside a function call or function definition. that semicolon got me thinking

Comment: Its inside the function definition

Comment: using debugger, can you please post n's content, just before executiong parse function call

Comment: just add debugger; before return. then you can inspect it's contents