# ASP.NET MVC bundling with optimization produces incorrect minified javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I turned on optimization using `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true`. Previously working javascript code now breaks with the following errors:

[image]

Clicking on the first error:

[image]

This corresponds to these two lines in the original source code:

[image]

The regexp in the first line and the variable in the second line were joined without any space.

How do I solve this problem without disabling optimization? I found a related question here but all answers resort to workarounds: [ASP.NET MVC 4 Script bundling causes errors upon deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379130/asp-net-mvc-4-script-bundling-causes-errors-upon-deployment)

Comment: Can you just put ";" in the end of rhtml line?

Comment: @KimHoang The source code belongs to a rather huge (227KB) framework (avalon.js, an alternative to vue.js/angular.js). I do not intend to modify the source code I didn't write.

Comment: If so, you cannot use minification of MVC bundle. Just separate it to another normal bundle like the link you reference. I also did that with vncsdk.js. Maybe you can find if there exists a minified version of avalon.js?

Comment: Yes. There is a minified version but I always have to include it as a separate dependency. Your solution is also a workaround. Probably MS didn't give much attention to System.Web.Optimization so this is an unfixed bug.

Comment: There are several minimizers, other than the default minimizer, that work with the bundle system. Google around and check NuGet. You can see if they work better for your purposes. My favorite is the Microsoft Ajax minimizer. Always works well for me. http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/System.Web.Optimization?page=1